# Specific graphic in R

Tags: r

I need some help to draw this specific graphic in R.

I would like to know if you have already worked with this kind of graph?
It's a graph that draws three points for each variable (like an arrow)

If you have an idea about it, or a library doing it, tell me about it.

Thanks you for the help.

[image]

That's an exemple of data
[image]

Comment: In base R, in shouldn't be difficult with `arrows` and `lines`. But my first reaction would be: are you sure you want to draw this? Doesn't look very readable.

Comment: Yes i'm sure, it's not very readable but it's required ...

Comment: If you want a more detailed answer than the comment above, please offer some sample data.

Comment: oh right, i will  add the data in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr`/`ggplot` version:

```r
library(tidyverse)
tibble(ID = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2,3)), year = rep(2018:2020, 2), x = c(1.2, 1.6, -1.1, 3.2, 3.8, 1.9), y = c(3, -2, 6, -1, 2, 3)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(label = ifelse(row_number() == 1, ID, "")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, label = label, group = ID)) + 
  geom_path(arrow = arrow()) + 
  geom_text(nudge_x = .2, nudge_y = 0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: if i wanna show the name of ID in place of ID how can do it ?

Comment: If you have a column with that information, use it in place of ID in my code.

Comment: What aboutthe row_number i will remplace it with what please?  `mutate(label = ifelse(row_number() == 1, ID, ""))`

Comment: Replace "ID" with your column name in that line.

Comment: i do, but it's shows me label = [9;2;3;4;5;1...] not the name of the id. The name of id is in character

Comment: If ID is a named vector, you could replace "ID" in the code snippet above with "names(ID)".  Or you could create a new column with just those names, and use that in place of ID in my code. FYI, it is hard to answer your question when we don't have the data you are using -- much better to share the actual data with `dput()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with an "old school" R plot.

```
db <- data.frame(id = rep(1:2, each = 3),
                 year = rep(2018:2020, times = 2),
                 x = c(1.2, 1.6, -1.1, 3.2, 3.8, 1.9),
                 y = c(3, -2, 6, -1, 2, 3))

with(reshape(db, direction = "wide", idvar = "id", timevar = "year"),
     {
       frame()
       plot.window(xlim = range(db$x), ylim = range(db$y))
       segments(x.2018, y.2018, x.2019, y.2019)
       arrows(x.2019, y.2019, x.2020, y.2020)
       axis(1, pos = 0, col = "gray")
       axis(2, pos = 0, col = "gray")
       box()
     })
```

[image]